# Setting up Firesotre security rules for read acttion for application without login autentication

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following rule in Firestore for `read if true` I recieve email that point anybody can read and my requests can be drained. I need some approach read action to be allowed only from my app.I don't have authentication in the app is accessible without registration.What can I do to restrict the access only from the app.I read can be set SHA1 key but not quite sure how to implement it.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
      allow read: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that but there is a way around just add Anonymously authentication with firebase Auth Ui this way users will not have to create an email and they will be authenticated

another way is: try to make some parts which doesn't require security public for anyone to read .

Answer (score 0):

I‘m afraid there’s **actually** nothing you can do.
Since you are using a backend as a service provider you will have to use some sort of authentication if you want to prevent certain people to execute certain actions.
This could be classic username/password authentication or a more modern means like oauth.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want your application code to be able to access the database, consider setting up [Firebase App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) for your project.

Comment: I will try it after I Initialize App Check in my app what rule i need to write in firestore rules I didn't find an example.Is this rule `allow read, write: if request.auth != null;`

Comment: App Check is unrelated to your security rules, and will actually reject reads/writes before they even reach your rules.